# How to Set all SqlDb rows in ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to set all the rows of a database in a listview so that i may click on that particular item to see that details in a full screen on next activity.

I am able to set all the rows in a textview but now I want to set it in a listview so that it may look better.

I searched regarding this and I got [this](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-show-data-from-sqlite-db-into.html) but I feel this code is used in a lengthy way. They took a class contact.java that I haven't and i feel that there's no requirement of that class. So if there is requirement than I may implement that code.

Is there any easier and smaller way to do this?

The code I used for setting it in a TextView is:

```java
String data = odb.getData();
        odb.close();
        tv.setText(data);


public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_WHOM,
                KEY_PRICE, KEY_ITEM, KEY_AMOUNT };
        Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
        int iWhom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHOM);
        int iPrice = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE);
        int iItem = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM);
        int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iDate)
                    + " " + c.getString(iWhom) + c.getString(iPrice) + " "
                    + c.getString(iItem) + " " + c.getString(iAmount) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: maybe this one? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: @mihail that's the same ok it means i have to use that class....ok thanks mihail

Answer (score 1):

There is tutorial on the Android developer site called "Notepad Tutorial". Go it has similas functionality to what you are trying to achieve. Here is the link to it:

http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Comment: its regarding how to make notepad

Comment: so replace the word "notepad" with "my app"

Comment: @devilAbhi you wanted a guide to show you how the set database content onto a list view. That guide has a database of notes who's titles are displayed on a list and when the user selects a title it shows the note content. Isn't that what you where looking for?